# Live Migration with JuJu

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, lxd

I have a juju setup and I'm using a manual cloud that mixes physical and virtual machines(VirtualBox). In my scenario, I have 7 services that are related and works perfectly.

Now, everything is OK but I need to move to a second step. I need to consider the case where a service is down (let's say that a machine is crashed), then I need to live migrate that service to another machine and then to re-add a relation (let's suppose that services colocation is not allowed). Lastly, I need that service keeps going to work (maybe except during the live migration).

Is it possible to do that with Juju? 
Should I integrate MaaS/Openstack/LXD to do that?

I've seen that OpenStack Live-migrating seems a possible way but any suggestion or advice from the community will be appreciated because I'm trying to focus my research.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can't "live migrate" when the server, physical or virtual, have crashed ie. is not live.

Comment: Ok, you're right, allow me to be more precisely. For example, I have 2 machines with a Database and a WordPress app (let's keep it simple), orchestrated by juju controller. Is it possible to backup (with regular intervals maybe) the database and then to migrate it into another instance (suppose that first machine stops working) of the same cloud? The important is that WordPress application keeps going to work (and a database is needed). Is this possible in some way?